# Make the specific routes in Express have higher priority than the dynamic ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two routes added in *this* order:

```
/:foo
/login
```

The way how my app is structured is that the routes may be added dynamically. So, I do want to catch any site page (e.g. `/hello-world`, matched by `:foo`), but I do want that the specific route `/login` to have higher priority than the other one.

I know that the middleware get executed in sequential order, so, ideally I have to change the order of the calls, but since this is happening dynamically, is there a better way to do it?

How can I tell Express that the routes without dynamic stuff in them (pretty much containing `:`) should have priority over the ones that are dynamic?

Comment: If you set up the router like this, /login matches /:foo before anyway

Comment: @LukasHechenberger That's what I was saying in the question. `:D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with "plain" Express, but this may work:

```
let Router   = express.Router;
let MyRouter = function() {
  let instance    = Router.apply(this, arguments);
  let handle      = instance.handle.bind(instance);
  instance.handle = function(req, res, out) {
    this.stack.sort((layer1, layer2) => {
      let path1 = layer1.route.path.replace(/:[A-Za-z0-9_]+/g, ':');
      let path2 = layer2.route.path.replace(/:[A-Za-z0-9_]+/g, ':');

      return path1.length < path2.length;
    });
    return handle(req, res, out);
  };
  return instance;
}
express.Router = MyRouter;
```

It basically monkeypatches the `handle` method of `express.Router` to sort the layer stack (which contains the routes) prior to handling the request. It sorts routes based on the length of the path (longer paths take priority), and hardcodes parameters in paths to have a length of 1 (so `/:foo` has a length of 2, and `/` has a length of 1; if you have paths like `/x`, you may have to fix this).

Very much untested, but at least it may provide an idea on how to tackle this.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. How I ended up was just by checking if `:` is in the url and since I'm calling my own function for adding a new route, if `:` is in the url, I add it to a router object, otherwise I add it to another router object. The last one has higher priority. :)

Comment: @IonicăBizău yours sounds like a much cleaner solution than my hack =D

Answer (score 4):

You should place a route with the higher priority early than other.

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.send('login');
});
app.get('/:foo', (req, res) => {
    res.send('fooooo');
});
```

Then it will work